# Model binding is not properly working in input parameter controller in .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to Alldata transfer a from Model to ViewModel. But the input parameter can't input several data. For that this data I can not use my session to create a cart system. Here is my code.

```
public class ProductVm: Spray
{ }
```

```
 public class Spray
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public String Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public String Image { get; set; }


        public String Image1 { get; set; }
        [Required]

        public String ProductColor { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date { get; set; }


        [Required]
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Size { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public String Description { get; set; }


        [Display(Name = "Product Type")]

        public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ProductTypeId")]
        public ProductTypes ProductTypes { get; set; }
    }
```

[HttpGet]

```
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var hi = _db.Spray.Include(c => c.ProductTypes).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

        ProductVm product = new ProductVm
        {
            Name = hi.Name,
            Id = hi.Id,
            Image = hi.Image,
            Quantity = hi.Quantity,
            Price = hi.Price,
        };
       

        if (product == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(product);
    }



    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Details")]

    public async Task <IActionResult> ProductDetails(ProductVm pb)
    {

        List<Spray> sprays = new List<Spray>();

        //if (id == null)
        //{
        //    return NotFound();
        //}

        //var yes = _db.Spray.Include(c => c.ProductTypes).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

        ProductVm product = new ProductVm()
        {
            Name = pb.Name,
            Id=pb.Id,    
            Image=pb.Image,
            Quantity=pb.Quantity,
           Price=pb.Price,
            
        };
      

        if (product == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        sprays = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<Spray>>("sprays");
        if (sprays == null)
        {
            sprays = new List<Spray>();
        }
        sprays.Add(product);
        HttpContext.Session.Set("sprays", sprays);

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

```
@model ProductVm


@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details.Cshtml";
}


@*@using OnlineShop.Utility
    @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
    @inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
    @{

        List<Laptop> laptops = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Get<List<Laptop>>("laptops");
        Laptop laptop = null;
        if (laptops != null)
        {
            laptop = laptops.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == Model.Id);
        }


    }

    <br />*@


<h2 class="text-info"> Product Details</h2>
</br></br>


@*<form method="post" asp-action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">*@
    <form method="post" asp-action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-1">

                <img src="~/@Model.Image" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
                </br></br>
                <img src="~/@Model.Image1" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
            </div>

            <div class="col-4 container">
                <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
                <img id="expandedImg" style="width:100%">
                <div id="imgtext"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <h2>@Model.Name</h2>

                <p><b>@Model.Description</b></p>

                <h4>@Model.Price $</h4>

               
                <small class="text-danger">Clearence</small>
                </br>
                <hr>
                <h4>Size:@Model.Size</h4>
                <h6>Product Color:@Model.ProductColor</h6>
                </br></br></br></br>


                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 spinner-block">
                    <div class="number-spinner">

                        <div class="input-group number-spinner">
                            <b class="mr-4"> <label asp-for="@Model.Quantity"></label></b></br>
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number btncartsniper" data-type="minus" data-dir="dwn"><span class="fa fa-minus fa-sm"></span></button>
                            </span>
                            <input asp-for="@Model.Quantity" class="form-control input-number Snippper_qty" value="0" type="number">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number btncartsniper" data-type="plus" data-dir="up"><span class="fa fa-plus fa-sm"></span></button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
                @*@if (Model.Quantity > 0)
        {
            <h1>This Product Is InStock</h1>
        }
        else
        {
            <h1>Not InStock</h1>
        }*@
                </br>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark form-control" value="Add To Cart" />
            </div>


        </div>
```

below picture, I am successful to transfer data to ViewModel but next failed to data-bind.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzFH1.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnyfP.png)

I am a beginner. Please, anyone, help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can't scope this image under input tag

As @Ben mentioned, you can use **hidden input** to store the value that img needs to pass like:

```
<img src="~/@Model.Image"  style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Image">
```

Another way is to use **ajax** to pass any model you want:

```
  <img src="~/@Model.Image" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);" data="@Model.Image">
        
    <script>
             var productVm =
                {
                    //other fields
                    "Image": $("#Image").attr("data"),
                }
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/Details',
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: JSON.stringify(productVm)
                });
    </script>
```

Comment: @Pritomsarkar, If this helps you solve your problem, please accept it as an answer. This will help others who have the same problem find the answer more easier.

Comment: extremely sorry for the late.

Answer (score 0):

Your Quantity property is passing back through `pb` because it has an `<input>` property.

You need to make sure anything you want to pass back to POST action has an `input` tag associated with it. If you don't want the user to see it, `type="hidden"` is a good candidate. However, if those fields are not editable by a user you could simply just grab them in the POST action too if you need them.

Comment: I want the user to see and change my quantity.but my above controller (Httpost) is received just users changeable quantity and id.can not receive another property.that means not totally data-bind here. that means here was not totally data-bind. but I want all data-bind data for using my cart system. I don't understand actually how I fix this problem.

Comment: Add anything you want to return back to your model as a hidden input.

Comment: Thanks, finally succeeded data-bind, but Image did not bind because can't scope this image under input tag, for that problem, what should I do.

Comment: If all you need is a string, just add a hidden input with the image url string? To be honest, from what I can see from your code the user is only allowed to input just a few things - everything else can be sent to the view, but shouldn't be sent back through the view model. Grab that information server side so that clients cannot accidentally or maliciously modify those fields.